# error in adding items in ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android

Error :-

```
 cannot resolve symbol add
 cannot resolve symbol setAdapter
```

I have imported ArrayList and ListView

When I run the application, it shows that your file has errors and hence can't run it.

```
package com.example.listviewdemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    ArrayList<String> myFamily = new ArrayList<String>();
    myFamily.add("Neha");
    myFamily.add("Ishaan");

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFamily);
    myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

Comment: your code is not inside any method, put it in onCreate brackets

Comment: Yeah.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is outside of the oncreate and didn't getting call from anywhere.Do it like that.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    ArrayList<String> myFamily = new ArrayList<String>();
    myFamily.add("Neha");
    myFamily.add("Ishaan");

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFamily);
    myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```